# Apache won't start after update

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew, php-7.2

`Apache` won't start after updating it and `php` to **7.2**

I was trying to update my php version from 7.1 to 7.2, but then apache didn't use it, so i update it as well. Now I have php 7.2 installed and XAMPP 7.2.22. But when I try to start it, it says `'Starting...'` for a while and then `'Stopped'`

The error_logs only show this:

> [Tue Sep 10 11:10:38.878211 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 105]
>   AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>
> [Tue Sep 10 11:11:19.745774 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 104] AH00163: Apache/2.4.34 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
>
> [Tue Sep 10 11:11:19.866352 2019] [core:notice] [pid 104] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'

Comment: Did you make sure there are no other httpd processes running before starting it?

Comment: @Amine Zaine with `sudo brew services list` it shows me that it is stopped, with `sudo killall httpd` no output and with `sudo apachectl stop` the output is `httpd (no pid file) not running`, when i try to force quit the two in the Activity Monitor others start. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this last week. I used `sudo apachectl stop`, but the "/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND" process was still running. So, I did this:

```
$ ps -ef | grep httpd
    0    83     1   0  8:40AM ??         0:00.39 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  501  2245   993   0  9:15AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep httpd
$ sudo kill -9 83
$ ps -ef | grep httpd
  501  2422   993   0  9:20AM ttys000    0:00.00 grep httpd
$ sudo apachectl start
```

All was well after that!

Be sure to check your httpd.conf file to make sure it is unchanged, too.